# Can not create azure batch pool in virtual network

Tags: azure, pool

I am getting an error while creating an azure batch pool, I have created a batch account without public address, in a vnet, also created and disabled the private link, when I execute az CLI

`az batch account login -g myRg --name myPool --shared-key-auth`

`az batch pool create --id myPoo-windows --os-family 4 --target-dedicated 2 --vm-size small`

to crate batch pool it throws an Authorization error `This request is not authorized to perform this operation`

Am not sure at this stage, even though I have had my RBAC as a contributor on the resource
any help is much appricaited

Comment: Given your repeated `batch pool` and `batch account` statements, are you sure that the [[tag:batch-file]] tag is appropriate for your question?

Comment: @Compo   to  be precise Azure  batch-pool is appropriate

Comment: Where is the batch file code you'd like us to help you with? All you have posted are command lines. The shell used for those, and the method used to run them are irrelevant, unless you expand upon your question to suggest otherwise.